# drivers not detected on laptop

Tags: wireless, 13.04, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 with both windows 7 64 bit and ubuntu 13.04 64 bit running side by side. windows 7 has managed to pick up all drivers but ubuntu has not.

any ideas as to how i can solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: Drivers for what?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the drivers can be found in software manager and some on the manufacturer websites. Try to search for drivers of your computer. That may help.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but i cant get onto internet either without using windows 7. Ubuntu is not detecting any driver, even if i use a code like: lpci -nn                                                             please advise how to find or where to download drivers